# XML / PHP Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml, document

i am having an error in my xml (Extra content at the end of the document), i have searched all over the internet but not anysolution worked.

i have read something about a root or document, but did didnt take away my problem.

PHP:

```
<?php $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$query = "SELECT * FROM leden";
while($q = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{ 
$user = $doc->createElement('user');
$user = $doc->appendChild($user);
$title = $doc->createElement('id');
$title = $user->appendChild($title);
$text = $doc->createTextNode($q['id']);
$text = $title->appendChild($text);
$title = $doc->createElement('nickname');
$title = $user->appendChild($title);
$text = $doc->createTextNode($q['gebruikersnaam']);
$text = $title->appendChild($text);
//etc.. etc
}
echo $doc->saveXML($doc);
?>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<user>
<id>300</id>
<nickname>Peterjhonsen</nickname>
<url>http://www.abcd.nl/leden/peterjhons&amp;refid=123&amp;cp=gg</url>
<foto>http://www.abcd.nl/image.php/uploads/2013043003560sdfsdfl2340.jpg?width=100&amp;height=100&amp;cropratio=1:1&amp;image=/uploads/20130430sdfsdf2340.jpg</foto>
<leeftijd>55</leeftijd>
<geslacht>man</geslacht>
<postuur>Vol</postuur>
<provincie>Belgie</provincie>
<ras>Blank</ras>
<profieltext>Lorem ipsum</profieltext>
<refid>530</refid>
</user>
<user>
<id>422</id>
<nickname>Jackson</nickname>
<url>http://www.abcd.nl/leden/timmerman&amp;refid=530&amp;cp=gg</url>
<foto>http://www.abcd.nl/image.php/uploads/25201842tidsfsrman.jpg?width=100&amp;height=100&amp;cropratio=1:1&amp;image=/uploads/25201842sdfsdf.jpg</foto>
<leeftijd>27</leeftijd>
<geslacht>man</geslacht>
<postuur>Normaal</postuur>
<provincie>Noord-Brabant</provincie>
<ras>Blank</ras>
<profieltext></profieltext>
<refid>530</refid>
</user>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent for all your users, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userlist>
    <user>
        <id>300</id>
        <nickname>Peterjhonsen</nickname>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>400</id>
        <nickname>Fred</nickname>
    </user>
</userlist>
```

simply insert this after line 1:

```
$root = $doc->createElement('userlist');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);
```

and change the code after the `while` accordingly:

```
...
$user = $root->appendChild($user);
```